# IONIC 2 getting return value after HTTP call

Tags: angular, http, ionic2

I have an alert in my service that looks like this:

```
status(id, name) {

let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'title',
    message: 'Random Message', 

    buttons: [
    {
        text: ' Reject',
        handler: () => {
            console.log('Disagree clicked');
            let nav=this.app.getActiveNav();
            nav.push(this.newPage)
        }

    },
    {
        text: 'Accept ',
        handler: () => {

            //apply
            let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization':   localStorage.getItem('token') })

            // checking if resume is available
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.http.get(this.applicant +"id=" + id + "&name="+name,{ headers:headers }).subscribe(
                    (res)=>{
                        console.log (res.json())
                        resolve(res)
                        return res
                    },(err)=>{
                        console.log (err)
                        reject(err)
                    }) 

            })

        }
    }]
});
confirm.present();
}
```

this method works.

Now in my page.ts when I call this method, I want to be able to say: if there is a result then do something.  I tried this:

```
this.applicationProvider.status(id,name).then (result=>{
        console.log (result)
    })
```

but I got get anything back.

Comment: Should the first instance of result not be (result) ? It looks like you're declaring a function called result and passing it no arguments.

Comment: You shouldn't be using something related to the view (in the case, the AlertController) in a service. This is an anti-pattern. Anyway, your status() method does not return a Promise, so you don't have a value to do .status(id,name).then()

Comment: what can I change to make my code better? I'm still a beginner at ionic 2 @daveyfaherty

Comment: what can I change to make my code better? I'm still a beginner at ionic 2 @Christian Benseler